# Cannot resolve method 'into(ImageView)'

Tags: imageview, picasso

Picasso.get().load("https:".concat(modal.getIcon())).into(holder.conditionIV);

No candidates found for method call Picasso.get().load("https:".concat(modal.getIcon())).into(holder.conditionIV)

please help me to solve this error. There is an error in "into"

I try to implement latest version of picasso